# Word VBA search sentence for certain words

Tags: vba, ms-word, find, wildcard

I am working on a small script to check my word document. Part of that checking process is checking if I used words that are prohibited. I made a database in MS Access and loading that DB into Word worked.

The part that does not work it actually checking if one of the words from the database is used. I am looping each sentence and perform the check below:

"RS" is the loaded database table, "Selection" = the active sentence, "Cword" is the variable for the prohibited word and gets changed while looping through the database table

```
        'Word check
        RS.MoveFirst
        While Not RS.EOF
            Cword = LCase(RS!Woord)
            PCword = LCase(RS!Pre)

            With Selection.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = True
                While .Execute(FindText:=" " & Cword & " ", Forward:=True)
                    If .Found = True Then
                        Oms = RS!Omschrijving
                        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(Selection.Range, Oms).Author = ComAut
                        VB_count = VB_count + 1
                        RS.MoveLast
                    End If
                Wend
            End With
        Wend

        'number check
        With Selection.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = True
            While .Execute(FindText:=" [0-9] ", Forward:=True)
                If .Found = True Then
                    SingleNumber = Selection.Range
                    Tientallen = SingleNumber Mod 10
                    Hondertallen = SingleNumber Mod 100
                    Duizendtallen = SingleNumber Mod 1000
                    If SingleNumber <= 0 Or Tientallen = 0 And SingleNumber <= 100 Or Hondertallen = 0 And SingleNumber <= 1000 Or Duizendtallen = 0 And SingleNumber <= 12000 Then
                        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(Selection.Range, "dit getal bij voorkeur voluit schrijven. Uitgezonderd van bijvoorbeeld leeftijden, exacte waarden, maten, temperaturen en percentages").Author = ComAut
                    End If
                End If
            Wend
        End With
```

What I expect it to do is look for each prohibited word in the sentence and if found, add a comment with a small description. The problem is within the with find section since I added that part and before it worked. When I execute the code, word freezes and I have to force close it.

Any help is appreciated since this part is bothering me for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to add `RS.MoveNext`. Without this, the code was never able to reach `End of Field` in the first while loop since the database table consists of more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from the fact that the term being searched is not being removed or changed. Thus, in every loop the term being searched *is* the `Selection`, so it keeps finding the same thing, over and over. Word isn't freezing, it's in an "infinite loop". If you were to press Ctrl+Break the macro would eventually stop executing and you'd probably see hundreds or even thousands of comments pointing to the same position in the document...

The way to avoid this is to move the selection beyond the "found" term before the next loop starts - like pressing right-arrow on the keyboard. Something like this:

```
        With Selection.Range.Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .MatchWildcards = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop  'Prevent Word from starting again at the beginning of the document
            While .Execute(FindText:=" " & Cword & " ", Forward:=True)
                If .Found = True Then 'Not really necessary since the "While" already checks this...
                    Oms = RS!Omschrijving
                    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(Selection.Range, Oms).Author = ComAut
                    VB_count = VB_count + 1
                    RS.MoveLast
                    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'like pressing right-arrow key
                End If
            Wend
        End With
```

Comment: Hey, I found the problem, see my answer to this topic. Thanks for helping. Your answer was still valuable since I didn't know the .wrap and collapse properties

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through sentences and making selections, you can use Find/Replace on the entire document without selecting anything:

```
Cword = LCase(RS!Woord)
Oms = RS!Omschrijving
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<" & Cword & ">"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Comments.Add(Range:=.Range, Text:=Oms).Author = ComAut
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
RS.MoveLast
```

Note, too, the difference in the *wildcard* Find expression; mine will find strings that begin lines after a tab, paragraph break or line break and strings followed by any of those or a punctuation mark, as well as strings preceded/followed by spaces.

Comment: Hey, I found the problem, see my answer. Still thanks for the answer. I can't search the entire document for specific words since the database I am looping through consists of multiple items. Besides, I also preform some checks on each sentence so that is why I loop through each sentence instead of the entire document.

Comment: @Vinc199789 The mere fact there are multiple items doesn't negate the approach my code takes; it is still far more efficient than a sentence-based loop, even if you need that approach for other purposes. As for looping through sentences, you need to be aware that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following: *Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.* For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

Comment: I changed the script to a document-based loop instead of a sentence-based loop and it did the check part much faster. Thanks for the tip. I didn't expect it to be this faster.